# What is the advantage of designing deterministic distributed algorithms?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, dc.distributed-comp, fault-tolerance

Distributed algorithms that are resilient to failures can either be deterministic or probabilistic. Take for example the consensus problem.

- Paxos is deterministic in the sense that given the assumption it makes, it *always* works.
- In constrast, randomized consensus works with a given probability.

What is the advantage of designing and using a deterministic algorithm?

The assumptions upon which deterministic algorithms rely have also a probability of holding in the reality (what is called their *assumption coverage*). Hence, there is always a probability that a deterministic algorithm does not work in the reality.

Comment: [Paxos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)) /  wikipedia, family of protocols

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your comment?

Comment: It is good to note that randomization is used typically for liveness properties not safety properties. Safety properties always hold, however there is a chance that the algorithm does not terminate (which typically decreases as time passes).

Answer (score 10):

I will answer this from the perspective of **distributed graph algorithms** (distributed algorithms that solve a graph problem related to the structure of the communication network).

Here are some non-obvious reasons for designing deterministic distributed algorithms in this setting:

- **Subroutines in randomised algorithms**. On p. 12–13 of [these slides](http://adga2013.hiit.fi/elkin.pdf), Elkin outlines an algorithm design technique in which you can use a fast *deterministic* distributed algorithms as a subroutine in order to construct a fast *randomised* distributed algorithm. Interestingly, it is *not* possible to use a typical randomised algorithm as a subroutine in the same context (the error probability would be too high).
- **Fault tolerance**. There is a mechanical translation that allows you to convert a fast *deterministic* distributed algorithm into a fast *self-stabilising* distributed algorithm (see e.g. Section 2.4 of [this survey](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/suomela/doc/local-self-stab.pdf)). A similar conversion is not known for randomised algorithms (and I think it is unlikely to exist in the general case).